# ERROR:No contact points for [cas_native] when running the lagom project in conductr sandbox locally and cassandra separately in local?

Tags: cassandra, lagom, conductor

I have a lagom project and I am using external cassandra so the actual problem is when i am running my project on conductr locally using sandbox it is not able to detect cassandra running separately on my local.

> Error : Could not find Cassandra contact points, due to: No contact
>   points for [cas_native]

My build.sbt contains

```
lagomCassandraEnabled in ThisBuild := false
lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("cas_native" -> "http://localhost:9042")
```

Comment: Yes, cassandra is running on localhost. if we run "cqlsh" then we are in the cql shell.

Answer (score 0):

The `build.sbt` configuration above only applies when running in development mode.

See the Lagom documentation for information on configuring the service locator for production:

- [Running Lagom in production (Java)](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/java/ProductionOverview.html)
- [Using Akka Discovery (Java)](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/java/AkkaDiscoveryIntegration.html)
- [Running Lagom in production (Scala)](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/ProductionOverview.html)
- [Using Akka Discovery (Scala)](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/AkkaDiscoveryIntegration.html)

Comment: the url is no longer valid. I am encountering similar issue. Can you please provide latest url? Thanks

Comment: @WantIt I updated the answer with links to the latest documentation. I'm assuming that you are not using ConductR, as the original poster was, since ConductR is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you should chnage from "http://localhost:9042" to "tcp://localhost:9042", accounding to official documents [https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/CassandraServer.html#:~:text=tcp%3A//localhost%3A9042](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/CassandraServer.html#:%7E:text=tcp%3A//localhost%3A9042)

in sbt:

```
lagomCassandraEnabled in ThisBuild := false
lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("cas_native" -> "tcp://localhost:9042")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).